# When importing modules in ASN files, how do we get those modules or set it up for import?

Tags: asn.1

I am trying to relate this to python. In python, if we are using some commands related to the plotting library `matplotlib`, it tells us to import `matplotlib` and we do it by using `import statements`. In ASN files, how do we do the same? Any resource or pointers regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Using `IMPORTS` keyword: https://www.obj-sys.com/docs/acv60/CCppUsersGuide/CCppUsersGuide164.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IMPORTS clause is what you use to indicate you want to refer to some assignments (types, values, etc.) defined in another module.  ITU-T X.680 has all of the details.  Note that the ASN.1 standard doesn't say anything about how ASN.1 modules are to be organized within files, or how a tool should locate a referenced module's definition (i.e. which file to look in) - that's left for individual tools to decide.

Unfortunately, the rules around modules, IMPORTS, and EXPORTS are complicated.  Below is a summary, with references to X.680.  For the full syntax, refer to the [spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/t-rec-x.680/en).

### Module Uniqueness

Module names are required to be unique (13.7) but X.680 anticipates them not being unique (13.10).  An OID is supposed to uniquely identify a module (13.8).

### EXPORTS Statement

The EXPORTS statement has 3 possibilities:

1. EXPORTS SymbolsExported ";"

   - Exports all of the listed symbols.
   - You may export any symbol you define or import into the current module.  The exported names must be unique among the (local) definitions and imported symbols.
   - If the list is empty, nothing is exported.
2. EXPORTS ALL ";"

   - Exports all symbols that could have been exported explicitly (i.e. the set of unique names)
3. empty

   - Equivalent to the above; exists for backward compatibility

### IMPORTS Statement

The IMPORTS statement has 2 possibilities:

1. IMPORTS SymbolsImported ";"

   - Basically, you list the modules you want to import from, along with the symbols to import for each module.
   - The module name used here may differ from the declared name of the module, if the OID matches (13.10).  When the OID is given, it is definitive (13.11).  When a referenced module has an OID, the reference MUST use it (13.12).
   - The symbols you import may be defined or imported in the referenced module.  If the referenced module imports the symbol, it must be uniquely named (not also defined or imported more than once).
   - If the referenced module explicitly exports symbols, only those symbols may be imported.
   - The listed symbols are the only ones that may be referenced as an external reference (module.id) for the module being imported from.
   - If SymbolsImported is empty, then no external references (module.id) can be used in this module.
   - An imported symbol MAY be used without module qualification (13.19).  However, when referenced, an imported symbol MUST be qualified if there is any ambiguity (symbol also defined in the current module or multiply imported) and MUST be unqualified otherwise (13.20).
2. empty (no IMPORTS statement)

   - External references (module.id) are allowed.
   - Provided for backward compatibility.

References can be made as described above. A qualified reference must use the module name as given in the IMPORTS statement (which can differ from the declaration in the referenced module, though that is advised against), if the IMPORTS statement is present.  If there is no IMPORTS statement, then qualified references must match the name given in the referenced module (in which case, OID is obviously irrelevant).

In the latest version of X.680 (2/21), when importing a module using an OID, you can add a WITH SUCCESSORS or WITH DESCENDANTS clause.  The point is to enable using OIDs to version modules.  Basically, this makes it so that certain changes to an imported module's OID won't require updating the OID in the IMPORTS statement of any importing modules.